# Read multiple partitions from parquet using pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I partitioned a parquet file based on a year-months column.
After this I want to read multiple partitions of this parquet using pyspark but I can't find an eassy and short way of doing so. I tried:
`_df =  spark_sessions.read.option('compression','gzip').option("basePath", f"{_data['PQ_path']+_data['PQ_name_partitioned']}/").parquet(f"{_data['PQ_path']+_data['PQ_name_partitioned']}/ano-mes={_year}",f"{_data['PQ_path']+_data['PQ_name_partitioned']}/Anio={_year-1}",f"{_data['PQ_path']+_data['PQ_name_partitioned']}/Anio={_year-2}")`
and this works, but as you can see, if I wanted to replicate this for like 15 filters, I would have yo give 15 paths and it's not an automatic change.

On pandas I would do the following:
`_total_filter = [["partition-name","in","array with conditions"]] #Read parquet _df = pd.read_parquet(_path, engine='pyarrow', filters = _total_filter)`

Is there something like that on pyspark?

I tried:
`_df =  spark_sessions.read.option('compression','gzip').parquet(f"{_data['PQ_path']+_data['PQ_name_partitioned']}/Anio={_year}",filters=filter_array)`
like in pandas, but didn't work

Comment: If your file is partitioned itself, in case of pyspark you don't need to worry about partitioning it into multiple partitions. It will take care of that automatically.
I am not sure from your post that if you want to read complete file or just one partition from that file but based on your Pandas code I am assuming you want to read a particular partition. If that's the case you can just use filter on spark dataframe after reading your parquet file, while reading during the time of execution spark will read only that filtered partition because of PushDown filtering in case of Parquet files.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to read only specific partitions in order to make it faster. I compared what you say but if I read everything and then filter it is actually slower. I compared them like this:
https://i.postimg.cc/yxjJhhGL/comparision.png

Comment: The time that you are calculating isn't the correct way of calculating time in case of spark :) Spark uses lazy evaluation i.e. all the code that you have written will not get executed until and unless you call an action. Actions are like .show(), .count() etc. In the code that you shared, I didn't notice any action being called when you are calculating time. Also, is there any specific reason that you are using `compression` in options while reading the parquet files ?

Comment: Hi! I changed the code to add the .show() option but it stills has a time difference :(
I am using compression because I exported it with the compress option, I thought it was faster. Does it make it slower?

Comment: If you are really concerned about time, I would suggest looking on SparkUI, there it will tell you the exact time it takes for reading and all. Also, you can see the difference using `df.explain()` which shows the plan how the filter is working. Not sure time being added because of compression or not.